# Register A Module in Drupal Website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a module name twitter_widget and i used drupal 7 ,I want to register my module on drupal website.Please some one help me I am beginner with drupal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contribute your module by registering your account in Drupal.org. Visit here for more details to contribute to Drupal:

http://drupal.org/contribute/development

Comment: Step by step instructions can be found in slides 43-48 of my Git presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/ForestMars/gtfo-git-theory-for-opensource-repo-man-7836593

Answer (score 1):

Just put the module inside the folder `sites/all/modules`.

E.g. your module's absoulte path would be `http://YOUR_DOMAIN/sites/all/modules/twitter_widget/`.

That's all :)

Comment: I already put in sites/all/modules and it works fine but i want to upload a tar file on drupal website to another users please guide me how can i do this

Comment: Could you explain the case in more details?

Comment: Yes Sure I am working a project Social media marketing widgets I made a plugin name twitter_widgets of my project in drupal 7 Now I want to register it on drupal ,Because any user download and install it .Like I download Social_media_links.tar file from drupal and install and it works